# Using HTTPS with BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service)

Tags: security, https, windows-server-2003, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I am writing a client application that needs to send a file via BITS to my server.  I have everything working for the most part, but I can't get the BITS connection to operate securely with HTTPS.

Right now I'm just using basic authentication through HTTP, so the login is being sent cleartext--which is not optimal :-)  I would like to be able to use HTTPS, but am not sure how to go about doing this.  According to [this Google Groups thread](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.windows.server.networking/browse_thread/thread/1f1098a626b17443), BITS "doesn't support authentication using certificates" (though that comment is a few years old now).  Does this mean SSL is out?  How else can I secure a connection for BITS via HTTPS?

My server is running IIS 6.0 on Windows Server 2003.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BITS version 2.5 supports certificate based client authentication.  Check which version you have installed and potentially upgrade it to the latest.

Note sure if this is the latest, but here's a starting point:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923845

Answer (score 0):

BITS supports HTTP and HTTPS protocols. So if you have an SSL cert installed on your server and also installed in the Trusted Store on you client then I believe that BITS will work over HTTPS without any more intervention.